# std::thread and std::mutex issue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've got a global buffer (uint8_t dataBuffer[]) which a bluetooth communication thread is continuosly updating. At any given time my main program thread could access this same data buffer. The question is how do I prevent the main thread accessing the buffer while the other thread is updating it and vice versa?

At the moment my bluetooth thread does mutex lock() and unlock() around the buffer update. I have another mutex lock() and unlock() in my main thread as well when I'm accessing the data but this doesn't seem to work properly. For some reason I keep getting a lot of checksum errors which I'm pretty sure comes from a threading issue as I have another single threaded test app which is communicating with the same device pretty much flawlessly.

This is cut down version of what I do in my communication thread:

```
uint8_t dbuf[14];
while(1)
{
    if(!run)
        break;

    // Read data... //

    mtx1.lock();
    memcpy(dataBuffer, dbuf, 14);
    mtx1.unlock();
}
```

And in my main thread I have something like this:

```
mtx2.lock();
// Do something with dataBuffer
mtx2.unlock();
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: You're using [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) incorrectly.  You want to create one mutex and share it across threads.  [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) is an RAII safe way of locking the mutex if you want to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell, but it sounds like you're using two mutexes to protect one piece of data. That won't work. We want **one** mutex.

Let's look at a full example:

```
#include <thread>

std::mutex mutex;
int treasure;

void worker(int value) {
    while(true) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        treasure = value;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto t1 = std::thread(worker, 4);
    auto t2 = std::thread(worker, 5);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Things to note:

1. The [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) is shared between the two threads.
2. Each thread uses a [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) when it wants to access the shared data. You could also use a [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example! When you do a mutex lock in a thread, does that prevent the main thread accessing the shared data too?

Comment: The main thread is a thread just like `t1` and `t2`. So if it was to use a `lock_guard` as well, then it would be fine.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. I had only one mutex originally and was using it in my thread and in the main thread but it didn't change the communication errors so I'm beginning to think there might be some other issues with it as well. Back to debugging.. :)

Comment: Problem solved. At times when I was requesting X amount of bytes to read from the bluetooth stream I actually got less than X bytes in return. Didn't expect this to happen. Anyway. Thanks for the insights on the threading stuff!